# Get rid of extra empty category in QGIS categorized style?

Tags: qgis, style

I want to style my Data in a Categorized Style, with a Color Ramp according to a "Year".
But when I categorize my Data, QGIS creates a Categorie without a Value.
Thats a problem for my work, becuase my color ramp is starting and ending at a specific color.
So in my map there is the wrong color for the latest year.
So in my example picture 2017 must get the darkest green, and the other years would be a little bit darker then.
Is there an opportunity to tell QGIS ist should not create a categorie without a Value?

[image]

Comment: Does your dataset contain one / multiple records with missing "values" in the attribute field (that you choose for display)?

Comment: no, every feature does have a Value in this field.But Joseph's solution is working fine for me. thx

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I believe this is a standard QGIS behavour where all features are given a colour (including those without values in a selected field). What you can do is:

1. Remove the last symbol.
2. Change the **Colour ramp** to any other colour.
3. Choose the same green colour ramp again

This should *reset* your existing colours and set 2017 to be the darkest colour.

**Do not click Classify**.

Comment: @Riker - Most welcome, glad it helped :)

Comment: @Riker please, remember accepting the answer if it solved your problem: it will help future readers.